# Iterating multiple reasoned literals from the same property

Tags: jena, reasoning, pellet

The title may be a bit confusing but basically this is the problem: I am using *Jena* and a *Pellet reasoner* to produce property literals from a resource called *Patient_Doug*. The triple looks like this:
 `Patient_Doug-> hasSuggestion-> Literal` inferred suggestion.

The problem is that the Protege *Pellet reasoner* comes up with three suggestions for *Doug*, because *Doug* is in a pretty bad way in hospital. The *Protege reasoner* suggests that *Doug* needs a **Hi-Lo bed**, an **RF ID band** and a **bed closer to the nurse's station**. Unfortunatly, in *Jena*, I can only get *Hi-lo bed* to print. Only one of 3 literals.

Here is some of the code.

```java
    OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( PelletReasonerFactory.THE_SPEC );

    String ns = "http://altervista.org/owl/unit.owl#";
    String inputFile = "c:\\jena\\acuity.owl";  
    InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFile);
    if (in == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File: " + inputFile + " not found");
    }
    model.read(in,"");

    model.prepare();

    //inf and reasoner wont run unless i use hp libraries!

    //asserted data properties
    Individual ind = model.getIndividual(ns+"Patient_Doug");
    OntProperty abcValue = model.getOntProperty("http://example.org/hasABCValue");


    //inferred data properties
    OntProperty suggestion = model.getOntProperty(ns+"hasSuggestion");

    //print asserted data properties
    System.out.println("Properties for patient "+ind.getLocalName().toString());
    System.out.println( abcValue.getLocalName()+"= "+ind.getPropertyValue(abcValue).asLiteral().getInt());

    //print inferenced data properties      
    StmtIterator it = ind.listProperties(suggestion);

     //this iterator only prints one suggestion in an infinite loop
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("A posible suggestion= "+ind.getPropertyValue(suggestion).asLiteral().getString());
    }

    }
```

The code works fine but the iterator at the end only prints *only one subggestion* in an **infinite loop**.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.
Thanks.

Comment: Well, you should read again about *"how to use an iterator"* ...`it.hasNext()` just returns whether there is a "next" entry to iterate. `it.next()` would take the next entry. You never "used" the value of the iterator..now it's your turn...

Comment: Thanks AKSW I can always count on you for an illuminating reply.

Comment: Please add the answer once you figured out how to solve your problem. Might helps others as well (although for sure a duplicate on Stackoverflow regarding "how to use iterators in Java")

Comment: I think I will have to iterate while pellet is reasoning. So, I'm looking for a method like 'listInferredPropertyValues'. Pellet is reasoning three different values for the SAME PROPERTY  that is the challenge. I'll look at putting the reasoner in a TRY with an iterator. I'll still need next() in the iterator. I'll figure it out and post it here.

Comment: Not sure if I understood, but instead of `ind.listProperties(suggestion);` you should use `ind.listPropertyValues(suggestion)` to just get the values back (instead of whole Statements). Then just iterate over those values. This is trivial and Java basics. Not sure what you think is so complicated here. By the way, reasoning is done implicitly because you're using an `OntModel`. There is no need for some additional method.

Comment: I figured it out. I can iterate and print as many hasSuggestion the reasoner can come up with.          for (StmtIterator j = ind.listProperties(suggestion); j.hasNext(); ) {
                Statement s = j.next();
                //System.out.println( "    " + s.getPredicate().getLocalName() + " -> " );
                System.out.println( "A possible suggestion... " + s.getLiteral().getLexicalForm());
               
            }

Answer (score 0):

This code works to iterate and print the many inferred hasSuggestions. The hasSuggestion SWRL rules are in the OWL ontology

```
    OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( PelletReasonerFactory.THE_SPEC );

String ns = "http://altervista.org/owl/unit.owl#";
String inputFile = "c:\\jena\\acuity.owl";  
InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFile);
if (in == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("File: " + inputFile + " not found");
}
model.read(in,"");

model.prepare();

//inf and reasoner wont run unless i use hp libraries!

//asserted data properties
Individual ind = model.getIndividual(ns+"Patient_Doug");
OntProperty abcValue = model.getOntProperty("http://example.org/hasABCValue");


//inferred data properties
OntProperty suggestion = model.getOntProperty(ns+"hasSuggestion");

//print asserted data properties
System.out.println("Properties for patient "+ind.getLocalName().toString());
System.out.println( abcValue.getLocalName()+"= "+ind.getPropertyValue(abcValue).asLiteral().getInt());

    for (StmtIterator j = ind.listProperties(suggestion); j.hasNext(); ) {
            Statement s = j.next();
            //System.out.println( "    " + s.getPredicate().getLocalName() + " -> " );
            System.out.println( "A possible suggestion... " + s.getLiteral().getLexicalForm());

        }
```